# Replacing numbers to letters in dataframe in r

Tags: r, if-statement

So basically I have a column in a data frame like:

```
df <- data.frame(well = c("0","1",NA,"1","1","2","2","3","4","3"))
```

I just want to create a new column by replacing "0" to "A", "1" to "B",...,"7" to "H".
 I was trying this unsuccessfully:

```
lxn <-  data.frame(old_name = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
               new_name = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"))
map <- lxn$new_name
names(map) <- lxn$old_name
df <- df %>% mutate(well_l = ifelse(well %in% names(map), 
                     map[well], 
                     well))
```

If you try it you can see that the output is basically the well number + 1. I do not know why I am not retrieving the letters (new_name) and getting the number of well + 1.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: `merge(df, lxn, by.x = 'well', by.y = 'old_name', all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No loop required:

```
df <- data.frame(well = c("0","1",NA,"1","1","2","2","3","4","3"))

lxn <-  data.frame(old_name = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                   new_name = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"))

df %>%
  mutate(well = set_names(lxn$new_name, lxn$old_name)[well])

# well
# 1     A
# 2     B
# 3  <NA>
#   4     B
# 5     B
# 6     C
# 7     C
# 8     D
# 9     E
# 10    D
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, your simple code was enough to solve my problem!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the built-in constant `LETTERS`.

```
df <- transform(df, let=LETTERS[well])
df
#    well  let
# 1     0    A
# 2     1    B
# 3  <NA> <NA>
# 4     1    B
# 5     1    B
# 6     2    C
# 7     2    C
# 8     3    D
# 9     4    E
# 10    3    D
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is relying on the factor integer codes.  If it's a character vector it obviously won't work without converting to numeric and adding 1.

Comment: Thank you, my data had character vectors, so to not overcomplicate, I used the code provided by the r.user.05apr. It did the trick using dplyr, which was the thing I wanted. Thank you a lot.